# Move from multi repository rust project into workspace

Tags: git, rust

I worked on a rust project with multiple repositories but I learned about rust workspace and I want to switch to it. Is there a way to move my other crates into a submodule while saving the git tree of each of the repositories?
For example, I have repo a, b, with branches c, d, respectively, and I want to have a workspace with both projects and both branches for each of the projects.

Comment: Have you taken a look to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree ?

Comment: From what I can see this command doesn't allow me to take branches from different repos

Comment: Maybe something like this, with git merge? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories (I've never done it myself though)